# How to make images in carousel of the same size?

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4, styles

I have a carousel, and images have various sizes.  I want that images displayed in the same size. The problem is solved by adding `height`, but carousel lose it responsivity(when you enter from mobile device). This is code of my carousel:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
              @foreach($lastPosts as $key => $last)
                <div class="item @if($key == 0) active @endif">
                  <!-- post -->
                                    <div class="post post-thumb">
                                        <a class="post-img" href="/{{ $last->category->path }}/post/{{ $last->id }}"><img src="./img/posts/{{ $last->image->name }}" class="img-responsive d-block w-100" alt=""></a>
                                        <div class="post-body">
                                            <div class="post-category">
                                                <a href="/{{ $last->category->path }}">{{ $last->category->name }}</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <h3 class="post-title title-lg"><a href="/{{ $last->category->path }}/post/{{ $last->id }}">{{ $last->title }}</a></h3>
                                            <ul class="post-meta">
                                                <li>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($last->date)->format('d '.$months[date('n')].' Y') }}</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /post -->
                </div>
                @endforeach

              </div>
            </div>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please add a working demo/snippet which the rendered HTML and actual image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

you tried bootstrap img-fluid?

> Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width:
>   100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales
>   with the parent element.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/